# Calculate altitude in Android application

Tags: android, gps, altitude

Can any one suggest me how to calculate the altitude in android application.

I am using the "GoogleApiClient" and calling the method location.getAltitude() in                    onLocationChanged(Location location), but always getting 0.0,

Can any one suggest if above api is returning the correct value or there is any other way to calculate the altitude?

Comment: because device location is not higher than sea surface

Comment: no, at same place some other apps is showing altitude value - 197 meter

Answer (score 1):

First check `LocationProvider.supportsAltitude()` then after check `Location.hasAltitude()` if it returns true than you will get some altitude instead of 0.0 .